# JQuery, ID and Name attributes not updating

Tags: jquery

Any ideas as to why the ID and Name are not updating here?

```
function addQuestion(){
var currentQuestion = $(".questionContainer").size(); //Number of questionContainers
var $newElement = window.$pQuestion.clone().attr('id','questionContainer'+currentQuestion);
$newElement.children('#question0').attr('id','question'+currentQuestion).attr('name','quest ion'+currentQuestion);

//Update the answerContainer div id.
$newElement.children('#answerContainer0').attr('id','answerContainer'+currentQuestion);

//Update the first answer id and name
var answerId = 'question'+currentQuestion+'-answer1';
$newElement.children('#question0-answer1').attr("id",answerId).attr("name",answerId);
$newElement.appendTo('#questionArea');
}
```

The last few lines is where the issue seems to be. This should update to "question1-answer1" I have verified that the value of answerId is correct, just seems to not be applied to the ID and Name.

Let me know if you'd like more context.

Comment: How do you know they're not updating? Remember not all DOM inspectors update when JavaScript changes attributes. Best bet is to `alert()` out the attribute after setting it, just to check.

Comment: 1 problem (*might be just in the pasted code*) is the `'quest ion'+currentQuestion` in the forth line.. remove the space.. Also if you can post the relevant html (*a question / answer group*)

Comment: can you create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net to show the markup too?

Comment: @Gaby, yep just the paste of the code :) - Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X4nY4/

Comment: @Ben I did alert() the answerID and it was correct, is there a way to alert() the attributes of the $newElement

Comment: Yes, `alert( $newElement.attr('name') );`, you'll need to replicate this for each of them.

Comment: Hi Bob! I just saw your question :( a little late, but updated your fiddle with the correction: http://jsfiddle.net/Vum5d/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `#question0-answer1` an immediate child of the `.questionContainer` in the DOM ?

Or might it be nested deeper ? in which case you would need to use

```
$newElement.find('#question0-answer1').attr("id",answerId).attr("name",answerId);
```

---

**update**

seeing the posted code, indeed your element is not a child but a descendant, so use the suggestion above..

Answer (score 0):

try to insert this few alerts

```
//Update the first answer id and name
var answerId = 'question'+currentQuestion+'-answer1';

// this should display the expected id
alert(answerId);

// the display of this should be greater than zero else 
// #question0-answer1 is not an immediate child of $newElement

alert($newElement.children('#question0-answer1').length());

$newElement.children('#question0-answer1').attr("id",answerId).attr("name",answerId);
$newElement.appendTo('#questionArea');
```

I would recommend you to use .find() instead of .children()

```
$newElement.find('#question0-answer1').blah.blah;
```

Comment: Thanks ian, gaby was able to identify this pretty quickly so I marked his answer as green.

Comment: Welcome glad you find the answer :)